# Excel VBA How to delete rows based on the value of a cell in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, criteria, delete-row, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will automatically delete rows from a raw data file based on multiple criteria.  I have been able to create a macro that will delete rows where certain columns have blank values, but I also need to delete rows that have a date that is equal or greater than a date contained in a specific cell in another worksheet. I have been all over the internet but have not found an explanation that addresses this particular case or one similar enough for me to figure it out.  I am working on automating a number of other reports, and this is the final piece that I need to be able to finish several of them.  Here is the code I am trying to use.

```
 Sub Deletedatesbeyondreportmonth()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 With ActiveSheet

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    .Columns("E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">= sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")"

    .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

If I replace the criteria `sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")` with the actual value that is contained in the specified cell the macro works, however I need it to be able to run based off the value contained in that cell.  I have played with some syntax variations and got different error messages, but haven't been able to figure it out.  If I run this as is, it highlights the word Sheet2 on the criteria line and says:

> Compile Error expected: End of statement

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the nested double-quotes.  Try using double-double-quotes, like:

```
.Columns("E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">= sheets(""Sheet2"").Range(""C1"")"
```

Example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/isvvba/thread/61239b43-f16c-456a-9479-e41c19c228da).

Answer (score 0):

when you encapsulate VBA logic by quotes you actually hardcode the string, so it will use the text `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")` in the filter rather than evaluate the Range value. You need to use the following:

```
.Columns("E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")
```

Comment: Thanks so much Rob and Phillip! I have been able to get this to work, I do have a small followup question... What would be the proper syntax in cases where the cell value I want to use is located in a different workbook? Using the example above, I tried using `Workbooks("Executive Summary 2012.xslm").Sheets("Summary By Mode").Range("Q2").Value` but it gives me an error

Comment: Workbooks("Executive Summary 2012").Sheets("Summary By Mode").Range("Q2").Value

Comment: @user1925693: make sure to vote for helpful answers and accept the actual answer by clicking the check mark.